# ASP.NET C# Button for showing last page in datagrid grid vanishes on click

Tags: c#, asp.net, datagrid

Last page button code works if put inside of the If (!this.isPostBack), so I did a lot of research to try and understand the cause of my problem but could not figure out my specific issue, looked through all threads regarding this on stackoverflow as well but to no luck. What am I missing?

Also, I could not get the Excel export to work, I tried 3 different approaches that all led to a OutOfMemoryException, the latest is still in the method but commented away for further laboration.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/rzp9l.jpg

ASPX Code

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true"
CodeBehind="TestWebFormView.aspx.cs" Inherits="NameSpace.TestWebFormView"
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
<title></title>
</head>
<body>
<%--Form--%>
<form id="form1" runat="server" visible="true">
<asp:Hidden
        <div>
        <%--GridView--%>
           <asp:GridView ID="GridView" AllowPaging="true" PageSize="5" OnPageIndexChanging="GridView_PageIndexChanging" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="true" DataKeyNames="Column1, Column2, Column3, Column4, Column5, Column6, Column7, Column8, Column9, Column10, Column11, Column12, Column13, Column14"></asp:GridView>     

        <%--Last Page Button(Not done, Datagrid vanishes on click, Last Page & Export button remain in browser view)--%>
            <asp:Button ID="btnLastPage" runat="server" Text="Jump to last page" OnClick="btnLastPage_Click" />

        <%--Export Button (Not done, OutOfMemoryException, need to somehow divide the workload - Stored Proc in the SQL back end behind the components maybe)--%`>`
            <asp:Button ID="btnExport" runat="server" Text="Exp to Excel" OnClick="btnExport_Click"/>
         </div>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

Code behind

```
using System;
using DBComponentsLibrary;
using DBComponentsLibrary.NameDataSetTableAdapters;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.IO;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Drawing;

namespace Name
{
    public partial class TestWebFormView : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!IsPostBack)
                loadGridData();
        }
        private void loadGridData()
        {
            NameTableAdapter TA = new NameTableAdapter();
            NameDataSet rds = new NameDataSet();
            NameDataSet.NameDataTable Rdt = new NameDataSet.NameDataTable();
            TA.Fill(Rdt);
            GridView.DataSource = Rdt;
            GridView.DataBind();
            GridView.Rows[0].Cells[0].Visible = true;
}

        protected void GridView_PageIndexChanging(object sender, GridViewPageEventArgs e)
        {
            GridView.PageIndex = e.NewPageIndex;
            Page.DataBind();
        }
        protected void btnLastPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            int myNewIndex = GridView.PageCount - 1;
            if (myNewIndex != null && myNewIndex != -1 && myNewIndex < GridView.PageCount)
            {
                GridView.PageIndex = myNewIndex;
            }
        }
        protected void btnExport_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }
        //    //Response.Buffer = true;
        //    //Response.Charset = "";
        //    //Response.BinaryWrite(Bytes);

        //    Response.ClearHeaders();
        //    Response.Clear();
        //    Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=*.xls");
        //    Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.ms-excel";
        //    Response.End();
        //    using (StringWriter sw = new StringWriter())
        //    {
        //        HtmlTextWriter hw = new HtmlTextWriter(sw);

        //        //To Export all pages
        //        //GridView.AllowPaging = true;


        //        this.DataBind();
        //        //this.BindGrid();

        //        GridView.HeaderRow.BackColor = Color.White;
        //        foreach (TableCell cell in GridView.HeaderRow.Cells)
        //        {
        //            cell.BackColor = GridView.HeaderStyle.BackColor;
        //        }
        //        foreach (GridViewRow row in GridView.Rows)
        //        {
        //            row.BackColor = Color.White;
        //            foreach (TableCell cell in row.Cells)
        //            {
        //                if (row.RowIndex % 2 == 0)
        //                {
        //                    cell.BackColor = GridView.AlternatingRowStyle.BackColor;
        //                }
        //                else
        //                {
        //                    cell.BackColor = GridView.RowStyle.BackColor;
        //                }
        //                cell.CssClass = "textmode";
        //            }
        //        }

        //        GridView.RenderControl(hw);

        //        //style to format numbers to string
        //        string style = @"<style> .textmode { } </style>";
        //        Response.Write(style);
        //        Response.Output.Write(sw.ToString());
        //        Response.Flush();
        //        Response.End();
        //    }
        //}
    }
    }
```

Edit 2016-02-17 : Edited & Cleaned up code. Still have some bugs I am trying to fix. But development is going forward. If I get stuck on something specific I will make a new post. Thanks again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're setting the page number to the highest possible number representable with an In32 type.

```
protected void btnLastPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.PageIndex = Int32.MaxValue;
        DataBind();
    }
```

That should be

```
protected void btnLastPage_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        GridView.PageIndex = GridView.PageCount - 1;
        DataBind();
    }
```